# RegEx to find worksheet references in Excel

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I need to extract any reference to a worksheet in a formula using VBA RegEx.  Any worksheet reference will have a ! as the "end delimiter" but there are NUMEROUS scenarios that could determine where a match might begin.

Can someone help me figure out a pattern to use to get this accomplished?

Some examples:

```
    =SUM(A1:B10)                                --> nothing
    =SUM(Sheet1!A1:B10)                         --> Sheet1
    =SUM('Sheet4 a'!A1:B10,Sheet5!A1:B10)       --> Sheet4 a and Sheet5
    =SUM([temp.xlsx]Sheet1!A1:B10)              --> Sheet1
    =SUM('[temp.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:B10)            --> Sheet1
    =SUM('C:\temp\[temp.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:B10)    --> Sheet1
```

Comment: Why do you need to use RegEx to do this? I would assume `Range.Precedents` could be of use.

Comment: `Range.Precedents` doesn't work on remote references, which is definitely a scenario I'm dealing with.  Good answer, though.  No sense in inventing a process if the API already provides.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Sheet\d\d*(?:(?!'?!).)*(?='?!)`

[demo a](https://regex101.com/r/erytmW/1)
or
[demo b](https://regex101.com/r/gCMeQn/1)

Comment: Aha!  You set me on the right track, my friend.  Now to further the challenge... what if I don't know the name of the worksheets in question?  Because, honestly, I don't.

The only thing I know is that the beginning portion of a match would start with a character or number... it may or may not be enclosed by the single quote.  It may or may not be preceded by a opening paren (the first argument of a function) OR a comma (additional argument of a function).